# How do I redirect items to fill one column of chests at a time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have an iron golem spawner farm. This is how it's set up:

[image: Current Setup]

(it extends about 30 blocks, this is just a model)

I want to redirect items to fill one column of chests at a time so that one column of chests does not get disproportionately filled, so that once the first column is full, it starts filling the second, then the third, and on and on.

[image: Goal]

How can I do this using hoppers? I've tried using water to push the items into one hopper and redirect the items from there, but it doesn't work well since the iron golems float on the water and items get burnt.

An idea I had is to make the hopper I circled in the screenshot below first check if the hopper north of it is full. If it is, then it starts filling up the hopper to the right. I'm not sure how to achieve this, though.

[image: Second Idea]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the setup you have. (red arrows show hopper direction, red circle indicates hopper pointing down)
[image: Setup]
You'll need a setup like this instead!
[image: New Setup]

The green circles indicate that another hopper is below it to collect items; we'll call them the "unloading hoppers". With your old setup, whichever "column" the items landed in would be the chest that they end up in. You need to lead your items into the first unloading hopper, which will go to the 2nd once it fills up, and so on.

Comment: Never thought about using another row of hoppers. Thanks!

Comment: Further explanation: Hoppers below pull out items earlier than the upper hopper can push its item to the side. This only works if only one hopper points into the top hopper and no items fall into it, which is true in this case, because you have a wall above them.